# Pylance проверяет html-файлы как Python-файлы

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

Собственно, вопрос, как заставить игнорировать Pylance проверять html-файлы?
Формат файла определяется корректно: HTML, но в качестве обработчика ошибок почему-то запускается Pylance, который естественно всё красит красными линями.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно решение: Установить версию Pylance v2023.6.40.

Версия Pylance v2023.7.10, похоже кривая.